# Открытие ассоциированного файла

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь научить свою WPF программу работать с ассоциированными файлами. В App.xaml указал Startup="App_OnStartup", в App.xaml.cs создал соответствующий обработчик события:

```
    private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        if (e.Args.Length > 0 && e.Args[0] != null)
        {
            mainWindow.StartUpPath = e.Args[0];
            MessageBox.Show(mainWindow.StartUpPath);
        }
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
```

В итоге, по какой-то причине, если программа запускается напрямую через exe файл, то mainWindow и создается и открывается. Если же дважды кликнуть по ассоциированному файлу, то выводится только MessageBox с именем файла, а затем всё молча умирает. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Странно. А если в этот момент (пока есть MessageBox) приаттачить дебаггер?

Comment: Спасибо, обнаружил необработанное исключение в конструкторе MainWindow, связанное с использованием Environment.CurrentDirectory. При открытии ассоциированного файла, этот метод возвращает каталог открытого файла, а не exe программы, что нарушало дальнейшую логику.

Comment: Вот и хорошо. Может быть, напишете ответ, чтобы будущие поколения знали, в чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема возникала из-за использования в конструкторе mainWindow `Environment.CurrentDirectory`. Данное свойство возвращало путь к каталогу ассоциированного файла, а не к .exe моей программы, что и служило причиной дальнейшего нарушения логики и "умирания". Решением проблемы (в моем случае) стало изменение способа получения каталога с .ехе файлом с `Environment.CurrentDirectory` на `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`